# How can we read google spreadsheet in our project using GData?

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-api

I want to read google spreadsheet in my project any example?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html